# predict dropping svm observations

Tags: r, svm

I'm using using a support vector machine on the [Titanic](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data) dataset and some of the observations are not being predicted when using the `predict` function with my model.

```
library(e1071)
library(data.table)
library(ISLR)
titanic.index <- sample(891, 600)

titanic.train <- dat[index]
titanic.test <- dat[-index]

titanic. fit <- svm(Survived ~ Pclass + Sex + SibSp, data = train, kernel = "polynomial") 
titanic.preds <- predict(fit, newdata = test)
titanic.preds
length(titanic.preds)
```

Whenever I run this on my comp I get anywhere from 220 to 240 predictions, but the their are clearly 291 observations in the test data. There aren't any missing observations for these predictors. To make matters even more weird, when I build an SVM using the `auto` dataset in the `ISLR` package this same problem doesn't occur.

```
data("Auto")

auto <- as.data.table(Auto)

auto[, mileage := ifelse(auto[, mpg] > median(auto[, mpg]), 1, 0)]
auto[, mileage := factor(mileage)]


auto.index <- sample(392, 200)

auto.train <- auto[auto.index]
auto.test <- auto[-auto.index]

auto.fit <- svm(mileage ~ ., data = auto.train)
auto.preds <- predict(auto.fit, newdata = auto.test)

auto.preds
length(auto.preds)
```

I have no idea why this is happening. Any insight you can provide is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you have no missing values: Just check  doing this: `dat <- read.csv('yourfile.csv',header=T,na.strings=c(""))` and then check the output of `sapply(dat,function(x) sum(is.na(x)))`

Comment: I took a slightly different approach, but still showed no missing values for the predictors I'm using. Specifically, `sum(is.na(colname))` and this came up 0 for all predictors in question.

Comment: I was suggesting `dat <- read.csv('yourfile.csv',header=T,na.strings=c(""))` to replace any empty strings `""` as `NA` in data and the then use `is.na`. Because empty strings in your data are not equivalent to `NA`. So you need to explicitly identify and convert to `NA`